# Bug in Limit in version 11.1.0

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in version 11.1.0 and fixed in version 11.2.0**

---

The infinite limit

```
Assuming[a>0&&b>0,
  Limit[((1+a)*b*x)/Sqrt[1+(1+a)*b*x*((1+a)*b*x+Sqrt[1+(1+a)^2*b^2*x^2])],
    x->Infinity]]
```

gives the correct result `1/Sqrt[2]` on version 11.0.0 but gives the incorrect result `7/8` on version 11.1.0.

What exactly has changed and what are the pitfalls we need to be watching out for?

Comment: I am getting the same thing with V11.1.

Comment: I get the same with versions 11.1.0 and 11.0.1 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with assumptions. The limit `Assuming[a>0, Limit[Sqrt[a^2+x^2]/Sqrt[1+(x*(x+Sqrt[a^2+x^2]))/a^2], x->0]]` gives `a` on version 11.0.0 but gives `Sqrt[a^2]` on version 11.1.0.

Comment: A workaround is to substitute `x->1/y` and take the limit `y->0`.

Comment: Will be fixed in a future release. Apologies for any trouble this may cause. It was a consequence of some code churn involving `Series` with fractional powers, on branch cuts.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Despite this bug, I am very much happier with the way the new `Series` (in 11.1) handles branch cuts of logs and fractional powers.  I look forward to further development of `Series` in future releases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Works correctly again in version 11.2.0:

```
Assuming[a > 0 && b > 0, 
 Limit[((1 + a)*b*x)/
   Sqrt[1 + (1 + a)*b*x*((1 + a)*b*x + Sqrt[1 + (1 + a)^2*b^2*x^2])], x -> Infinity]]

(* 1/Sqrt[2] *)

$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)
```